# Windows: C++: Redirection from file to serial port (input)

Tags: c++, windows, redirect, serial-port

I have inherited some rather old software which connects to a serial port, formats the incoming data and displays and saves it.  The software is written in an old Borland compiler (C++ Builder 5.0), and uses CreateFile to open the port, followed by SetupComm for the comm parameters.

Someone has asked me to add new functionality:  Enable taking a recorded session, and replaying it as though it was coming in on the serial port.

I'm looking at several possible solutions, the easiest and quickest involving a second serial port and a null modem cable.  This isn't exactly what they had in mind, but it does solve the problem.  However, assume I don't have this option.  Is there any way to redirect a comm port to a file, so that when the "com port" was opened it would open the file and read from it?  Or is there a simple parallel way to open the file (the same call to CreateFile, for example), and bypassing the call to SetupComm so that the input would come from file if desired?

Since I do have the simple HW solution, I don't want to invest hours rewriting the code, but if there is a simple way of going about it, I'd like to know.

Comment: If you have access to the source code, can't you just change the call to `CreateFile` to open the file you want instead of the serial port?

Comment: There are tons of virtual serial port drivers, that allow you to either set up the port to read from a file or to set up one port to read from a second virtual port (nullmodem cable in software)

Comment: eznme - It's more complicated than that - that was my starting point.  The problem is type type of I/O which is expected, and the callbacks to serial events that aren't happening, etc.

Comment: Eugen Rieck -  That's the kind of thing I'm looking for, but haven't found one that I was able to make work.  Is there one that you've used which would allow this to work cleanly?  I tried one from billproduction.com, which, when I tried to set it up as input from file and output to serial port, blocked my apps use of the port.  I looked briefly at com0com on sourceforge, but haven't gotten around to trying it yet.  A quick glance at the readme didn't state that it would work from a file.

Comment: Eugen - went to com0com, downloaded it, and now have a solution using it.  In and of itself it doesn't "work from a file", but after understanding the way it does work, it was very easy to have the original program connect seamlessly to one virtual port, added some code which sent the file to another, and paired the two ports to receive one from the other without actual hardware.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll award somehow the reputation points to Eugen Rieck, the suggestion was his.  The way I did this was with a package called com0com, which is an open source virtual com port.  I wrote  a routine which sends to one virtual com port, connected the com port of the original software to another one paired with that one, and the funcationality is there.